# Copy array data to another array using vb6

Tags: arrays, vb6

How can I pass the data of an `Array` to another `Array` using `VB6`?

Comment: You want to copy the array?

Comment: yes, because I have a computation in my program I should retain the data of current time that's why I needed it. `Array2 - Array1` then after the computation I will pass the data of `Array2` to `Array1` so that the `Array1` must have already a value and the `Array2` must be empty

Answer (score 6):

In VB6, array is copied on a simple assignment.

```
Dim arr1() As Long
Dim arr2() As Long

ReDim arr1(1 To 10)
'Fill arr1 with data

arr2 = arr1
```

Comment: I think this only works if its dynamic but its definitely the simplest way.

Comment: +1 Just for fun: you can also use API calls but its much much harder http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_SliceLng.htm

Comment: @MarkJ When it comes to fun, it is more fun to create [linked subarrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11713408/11683) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Dim lArray1(3) As Long
        Dim lArray2(3) As Long
        Dim count As Long

        lArray1(0) = 1
        lArray1(1) = 2
        lArray1(2) = 3

        lArray2(0) = 10
        lArray2(1) = 20
        lArray2(2) = 30

        For count = LBound(lArray1) To UBound(lArray1)
            lArray2(count) = lArray1(count)
        Next count

        Erase lArray2
```

if its not fixed length you will need to use redim in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered my questions :) Thank you guys for the help but this is what I did.

```
'Delete items in Array first
            For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(time2) - 1
                time2(lngIndex) = time2(lngIndex + 1)
            Next
'Next thing is
'Insert items in Array
            For lngIndex = UBound(time1) - 1 To 0 Step -1
                time1(lngIndex + 1) = time2(lngIndex)
            Next
```

This code solve my problem :)