# VB: Saving an array

Tags: vba, vb6

This is probably trivial but I couldn't find an answer via Google.

In Visual Basic, is it possible to save an array to a variable and then restore that array to its previous self by setting it equal to that variable?

Example:

`Dim SomeArray(20) As Integer`

`X = SomeArray`

`{Do stuff to the SomeArray}`

`SomeArray = X`

I've tried this by using a variable X defined as a Variant, but that gives a compile error. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Thank you everyone for trying to help me out. I've posted my test VBA code below. I get a compile error already at the statement "X = SomeArray". I hope one of you can tell me where my error lies. Here's the code:

```
Dim SomeArray(), X() As Integer

Sub Macro1()

ReDim SomeArray(1 To 20)

X = SomeArray

For i = 1 To 20
  SomeArray(i) = i
Next i

SomeArray = X

For i = 1 To 20
  MsgBox "SomeArray(" & i & ") = " & SomeArray(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim X the same as SomeArray, As Integer.

Comment: Dim x(20) as integer = SomeArray

Comment: Not sure the goal, but you can always use a storage variable, and some for loops.

Comment: Look at the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903330/copy-array-data-to-another-array-using-vb6

Comment: @Scott Craner  I'm using VBA for Excel and when I define X as "Dim X(20) As Integer" I get a compile error at the statement "X = SomeArray".

Comment: @Jim Hewitt OK, but that seems trivial. I.e. I can make a copy by running through all instances of the SomeArray, but this is what I would like to avoid as my SomeArray is very large.

Comment: @Jens - I was referring to the answer after that one.

Comment: @Jim Hewitt Sorry for being dense, but I don't see the difference. Isn't the last answer also just a run-through of the entire array?

Comment: @Jens Maybe it's me.  I was referring to the one with 3 upvotes.

Comment: @Jim Hewitt Tried the answer with 3 upvotes. I still get a compile error. Perhaps that answer only works for VB6 and not VBA?

Comment: @Jens That answer works in VBA. Update your code, error message and error position.

Comment: just `Dim X() As Integer`

Comment: @cyboashu I've edited my question to show my code. Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: `Dim SomeArray() as Integer, X() As Integer` and it works for me

Comment: Also, need to declare `i`.

Comment: @Scott Craner THANK YOU!! Separating the Dim statements into 2 separate statements made it work. I don't understand why, but I'm happy it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare data type for first array as Scott said. Seems you are overly confused now, take a deep breath and copy paste this code. :) Revisit it after some time and everything will be clear. :)

```
Dim SomeArray() As Integer, X() As Integer

Sub Macro1()

ReDim SomeArray(1 To 20)

X = SomeArray

For i = 1 To 20
  SomeArray(i) = i
Next i

SomeArray = X

For i = 1 To 20
  MsgBox "SomeArray(" & i & ") = " & SomeArray(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Got it. But can you explain what the difference is between "Dim SomeArray() As Integer, X() As Integer" and "Dim SomeArray() , X() As Integer"?

Comment: Thank you. As you can probably tell I'm a bit of a novice at VB. :)

Comment: No worries. Every body starts as a novice only. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing in your example - you're not even using X

I assume you want to test transferring SomeArray into the X array

I'd just use a variant for X and do this

```
Dim SomeArray()
Dim X As Variant

Sub Macro1()

    ReDim SomeArray(1 To 20)

    For i = 1 To 20
      SomeArray(i) = i
    Next i

    X = SomeArray

    For i = 1 To 20
      MsgBox "x(" & i & ") = " & X(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```