# "Object required" assigning function result in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have the following function to parse command line arguments in vb6

```
Private Function GetProcessParams() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim result() As Variant
    Select Case Command
        Case "-all"
            Set GetProcessParams = allProcess.Items
            Exit Function
        Case "-new"
            For i = 0 To allProcess.Count
                Dim tmp As TableInfo
                Set tmp = allProcess(i)
                If tmp.isNew Then
                    ReDim result(i + 1)
                    Set result(i) = tmp
                End If
            Next i
            Set GetProcessParams = result
            Exit Function
        Case Else
            Dim subset() As String
            subset = Split(Command, ",")
            ReDim result(UBound(subset))
            Dim val As String
            For i = 0 To UBound(subset)
                If IsNumeric(subset(i)) Then
                    Set result(i) = allProcess(CInt(subset(i)))
                End If
            Next i
            Set GetProcessParams = result
            Exit Function
    End Select
End Function
```

At runtime, it stops at line "Set GetProcessParams = result" in Case "-new" with message "Compile error: Object required"

What's wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `Set`.

Comment: allProcess.items(i) perhaps?

Comment: What happens if your tmp.isNew condition is never met and the empty array is never reDimmed?

Comment: At compile time or at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Set` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa266283%28v%3Dvs.60%29) is only for assigning object references. Your `result` variable is an array of Variants, and arrays aren't object references in VB. If you want to copy an array into your own variable, [you only need a regular assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22903330/65839), without the `Set` keyword.